# Neo4j Login issue

Tags: neo4j

[Observe this Image about the Neo4j login issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoY3E.png)

**This appears when tried to login to Neo4j browser, This dosen't appear in the begining after few hours it appeared*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to have a URI defined, you need to put that in - which will be something like:
`neo4j://localhost:7687`

then you need to provide the user/pass you have setup - if it's the first time you've attempted to login - use `neo4j` as the user and password, and you should get in.